# How to calculate pValue from GeneralizedLinearRegressionModel using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, data-science, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to calculate the pValue using GeneralizedLinearRegression and getting the below exception.

```
    val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
      .setInputCols(final_columns)
      .setOutputCol("Feature")

val glr = new GeneralizedLinearRegression()
      .setFamily("binomial")
      .setLink("logit")
      .setMaxIter(1)
      .setRegParam(0.0)
      .setFeaturesCol("Feature")
      .setLabelCol("LM_2")
      //.setSolver("auto")

    val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(assembler,glr))
    val lrModel_general = pipeline.fit(indexedDF)
    val sum = lrModel_general.stages.last.asInstanceOf[GeneralizedLinearRegressionModel].summary.pValues

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No p-value available for this GeneralizedLinearRegressionModel
at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.GeneralizedLinearRegressionTrainingSummary.pValues$lzycompute(GeneralizedLinearRegression.scala:1480)
at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.GeneralizedLinearRegressionTrainingSummary.pValues(GeneralizedLinearRegression.scala:1468)
at com.cvs.scala.ml.model.LR_SqlDB_LocalMessageGrouping$.main(LR_SqlDB_LocalMessageGrouping.scala:172)
at com.cvs.scala.ml.model.LR_SqlDB_LocalMessageGrouping.main(LR_SqlDB_LocalMessageGrouping.scala)
```

Comment: Looks like summary isn't available for this model, happens when the hessian is not invertible. You should add a check, I think it is model.summary.isAvailable or something

Comment: when i use:
val sum = lrModel_general.stages.last.asInstanceOf[GeneralizedLinearRegressionModel].hasSummary. It returns true, which indicates that the summary is present in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's definitely about statistics first, so consider reading [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/328523).

As for your solution in Spark, I would suggest checking the class of model and avoiding giving summary for Ridge model as it is almost useless for this kind of model.

Comment: So here is the thing, the dataset i am using has high correlation among several columns due to which the model couldnt build the summary cout of that complex schema. After minimizing the correlation (figuring out important features) I was able to get the pvalues of all the columns using the GLM summary.Cheers!